# Image refreshed when using WYSIWYG/content Block

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I'm trying to import a content Block in to my Angular project.The content variation contains an image, and in my app when i try to do an action like hover a button or use a sidenav THE IMAGE gets loaded again. And i dont understand why those images get uploaded many times.

After looking more into it. The API that get content block have a header with `cache-control: no-cache, private`

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was not a real bug. When i inspect in my UI to debug, "Disable cache" is automaticly activated then the bug appears.